# Change the Sender(not From) on wp_mail() function

Tags: email, wp-mail

I'm using the Post SMTP Plugin, but I manually send email via the `wp_mail()` function.
The gmail client shows the correct From:, but when I switch to outlook or another email client, shows the different Sender: (the one that has been set up in the Post SMTP From: setting)

I have tried these filters, but only the `wp_mail_from_name` works:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', create_function('', 'return sanitize_email("test@abv.bg"); ') );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', create_function('', 'return "Test Testov"; ') );
```

How can I force-change that sender?

EDIT:
Paul G., in Gmail I see this: `from:    Correct Name <c.name@mydomain.com>`

and in another email client this:

`From:  Correct Name`

`Sender:    default@mydomain.com`  <---- This is wrong.

Comment: The sender email information wont change based on the client that READS the email, that's impossible. Unless I've misunderstood what you've written...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Disable PostSMTP plugin and delete if not used anymore it should cleanup.
Then in functions.php add the following lines

```
// Function to change email address
function sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return 'tim.smith@example.com';
}
 
// Function to change sender name
function sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
    return 'Tim Smith';
}
 
// Hooking up our functions to WordPress filters 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'sender_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'sender_name' );
```

Taken from : [WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-change-sender-name-in-outgoing-wordpress-email/)

Answer (score 0):

Switched the **Mailer Type** from PostSMTP to PHPMailer and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Please be kind enough to mark my answer, as i did state to disable PostSMTP and then perform override if necessary.

you can also have shortcodes that change the senders email and name based on the form that you are using etc, like hooking into GRavity/Ninja forms etc.

Comment: Many thanks for the points :)